# how can I make the first var in a array the default

Tags: javascript, random

I have an script for producing random quotes using an onClick. However, what I need is for a specific quote to open as the default. After that, onClicks should produce random results. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<button onClick="quotes()">ASK then CLICK</button>
<br>
<textarea id="txtbox" style="width:170px;  readonly></textarea>
<br>
<br>
<script>
    function quotes() {

        var aquote = new Array;
        aquote[0] = " This SHOULD ALWAYS APPEAR FIRST ";
        aquote[1] = "Think twice about this ";
        aquote[2] = "Save your money.... ";
        aquote[3] = "Real Estate is good ";
        aquote[4] = "Visit the Islands "

        rdmQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * aquote.length);
        document.getElementById("txtbox ").value = aquote[rdmQuote];
    }
    window.onload = quotes;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could display the default text in your HTML itself, and then change the textarea's value with a random quote.

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="txtbox">This SHOULD ALWAYS APPEAR FIRST</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
var aquote = [
    "Think twice about this ",
    "Save your money.... ",
    "Real Estate is good ",
    "Visit the Islands "
];

var random = -1;

function quotes() {
    var temp = random;
    // Make sure we do not display the same quote twice in a row
    while(temp == random) temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * aquote.length);
    random = temp;
    document.getElementById("txtbox").innerHTML = aquote[random];
}
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can reorganise your code like this and create dedicated functions for either a random quote or a fixed one:

```
<button onClick="randomQuote()">ASK then CLICK</button>
...
<script>
var quotes = [
    " This SHOULD ALWAYS APPEAR FIRST ",
    "Think twice about this ", 
    "Save your money.... ", 
    "Real Estate is good ";
    "Visit the Islands "
];

function randomQuote()
{
    showQuote(Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length));
}

function showQuote(index) {
    document.getElementById("txtbox ").value = quotes[index];
}

window.onload = function() {
    showQuote(0);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your only problem is syntax errors. You have an extra space in `getElementById("txtbox ")` and a missing quote in the style declaration for textarea, otherwise code works using :

```
document.getElementById("txtbox").value = aquote[rdmQuote];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CkaMW/

Comment: The OP wants `aquote[0]` to load first, which this answer does not address.